# Почему selenium выводит только одну позицию после парсинга

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Есть код парсера на Selenium, все работает отлично, но в таблицу заносится только одна позиция более 1000 раз, что могло пойти не так?

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pandas as pd
import time 
webdriver = r"C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\RozetaParcer\chromedriver.exe" ### put your browser driver's path

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer") ### here the website url

items = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".goods-tile__picture.ng-star-inserted")) ### here you put the class name of the HTML element which contains the data to scrap

total = []
for item in range(items):

        items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".goods-tile__picture.ng-star-inserted")
        for item in items:
            t_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__title').text
            t_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__price-value').text
            t_nal = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__availability--available').text
            
            new = ((t_name, t_price, t_nal))
            total.append(new)
            
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
df.to_csv('Rozetka_parcer_{cur_data}.csv')
print(items)
driver.close()
```

Comment: 1) Не вставляйте код в javascript-сниппет 2) В предыдущем вопросе в комментарии я уже писал, что у вас двойной цикл по элементам. Если у вас будет в `items` 100 элементов, то на каждую итерацию еще по 100 элементов будет добавлено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаги:

- Убрал ненужный внешний цикл
- Заметил, что внутри цикла у вас поиск выполняется от `driver`, что странно, это поиск по всей странице. Скорее всего, нужно `t_name`, `t_price` и `t_nal` искать относительно перебираемых элементов в цикле, поэтому поиск сделал относительно `item`

Пример:

```
import time 

import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


webdriver = r"C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\RozetaParcer\chromedriver.exe"

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer")

total = []
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".goods-tile__picture.ng-star-inserted")
for item in items:
    t_name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__title').text
    t_price = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__price-value').text
    t_nal = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__availability--available').text
    
    row = t_name, t_price, t_nal
    total.append(row)

driver.close()
    
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
df.to_csv('Rozetka_parcer_{cur_data}.csv')
```

Comment: В таком случае выдает ошибку
  total = []
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, исправил. В строке `driver.get(` потерялась закрывающая скобка

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, пожалуйста :)