# Message: no such element, почему не находит элемент, хотя селектор указан верно?

Tags: python, selenium

Не находит элемент по css селектору, хотя он указан верно

```
for item in items:
t_name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__title').text
t_price = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__price-value').text
t_nal = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__availability--available').text
```

Выводит:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".goods-tile__heading"}
> (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)

Вот страница с которой проходит парсинг: https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer

Вот код элемента:

```css
.goods-tile__title {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="goods-tile__inner" data-goods-id="6427678"><!----><!----><!----><span class="goods-tile__label promo-label promo-label_type_action ng-star-inserted"> −54% </span><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div class="goods-tile__actions ng-star-inserted"><!----><!----><!----><app-goods-wishlist class="ng-star-inserted"><!----><button class="wish-button js-wish-button ng-star-inserted" type="button" aria-label="Переместить в список желаний"><!----><svg aria-hidden="true" height="24" width="24" class="ng-star-inserted"><use href="#icon-heart-empty"></use></svg></button><!----><!----></app-goods-wishlist><!----><!----><app-compare-button class="ng-star-inserted"><!----><button class="compare-button ng-star-inserted" type="button"><svg height="24" width="24"><use href="#icon-compare"></use></svg></button><!----></app-compare-button><!----></div><!----><!----><a apprzroute="" class="goods-tile__picture ng-star-inserted" href="https://rozetka.com.ua/gazer_ckr4400/p6427678/"><img src="https://content.rozetka.com.ua/goods/images/base_action/10698517.jpg" class="ng-lazyloaded" alt="Парковочная система Gazer CKR4400 " title="Парковочная система Gazer CKR4400 "><img class="lazy_img_hover ng-lazyloaded display-none" alt="Парковочная система Gazer CKR4400 " title="Парковочная система Gazer CKR4400 " src="https://content.rozetka.com.ua/goods/images/base_action/10698517.jpg"><ul class="super-actions"><!----></ul><!----><!----></a><div class="goods-tile__colors"><!----></div><!----><a apprzroute="" class="goods-tile__heading ng-star-inserted" href="https://rozetka.com.ua/gazer_ckr4400/p6427678/" title="Парковочная система Gazer CKR4400 "><span class="goods-tile__title"><!----> Парковочная система Gazer CKR4400  <!----></span></a><!----><div class="goods-tile__rating ng-star-inserted"><!----><!----><a apprzroute="" href="https://rozetka.com.ua/gazer_ckr4400/p6427678/comments/" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----><div class="goods-tile__stars ng-star-inserted"><svg aria-label="Рейтинг товара 3.6 из 5" height="12" width="65"><g><defs><linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="ratingFill_6427678"><stop stop-color="#ffa900" stop-opacity="1" offset="86%"></stop><stop stop-color="#ffa900" stop-opacity="1" offset="86%"></stop><stop attr.offset="100%" stop-color="#d2d2d2" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop attr.offset="100%" stop-color="#d2d2d2" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient></defs><use xlink:href="#icon-product-stars" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="url(#ratingFill_6427678)"></use></g></svg><span class="goods-tile__reviews-link"> 5 отзывов </span></div><!----></a><!----></div><div class="goods-tile__prices"><!----><!----><!----><div class="goods-tile__price--old price--gray ng-star-inserted"><!----><!----> 16 899&nbsp;<small rzcurrency="" class="ng-star-inserted">₴</small></div><div class="goods-tile__price price--red ng-star-inserted"><!----><!----><p class="ng-star-inserted"><span class="goods-tile__price-value"> 7&nbsp;680 </span><span class="goods-tile__price-currency" rzcurrency="">₴</span></p><!----><app-buy-button extclass="goods-tile__buy-button" _nghost-rz-client-c55="" goods_id="6427678" class="toOrder ng-star-inserted"><!----><!----><!----><button _ngcontent-rz-client-c55="" class="buy-button goods-tile__buy-button ng-star-inserted" type="button" aria-label="Купить"><svg _ngcontent-rz-client-c55="" height="24" width="24"><use _ngcontent-rz-client-c55="" xlink:href="#icon-basket"></use></svg><!----></button><!----></app-buy-button><!----></div></div><!----><!----><!----><div class="goods-tile__availability goods-tile__availability--available ng-star-inserted"> Есть в наличии </div><!----><!----><div class="goods-tile__promo"><!----></div><div class="goods-tile__hidden-holder"><div class="goods-tile__hidden-content"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Смотрел сайт и там есть прогрузка элементов. Скорее всего, ваш поиска выполнился раньше, чем элементы прогрузились. Добавьте явные ожидания `WebDriverWait` или неявные через `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`, разницу между ними делал в качестве примера тут: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/f071aadf145a168f6929a88d3d1e649f03852334/selenium__examples/about_wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрел сайт и там есть прогрузка элементов. Скорее всего, ваш поиск выполнился раньше, чем элементы прогрузились. Добавьте явные ожидания `WebDriverWait` или неявные через `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`

Шаги:

- [Код взят из предыдущего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1337879/201445)
- Добавил с неявным ожиданием (`implicitly_wait`)
- Поменял селектор для получения `items` с `.goods-tile__picture.ng-star-inserted` на `.goods-tile.ng-star-inserted`, т.к. ранее возвращались не родительские элементы для товаров

Пример:

```
import time 

import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


webdriver = r"C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\RozetaParcer\chromedriver.exe"

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer")

total = []
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".goods-tile.ng-star-inserted")
for item in items:
    t_name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__title').text
    t_price = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__price-value').text
    t_nal = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__availability--available').text
    
    row = t_name, t_price, t_nal
    total.append(row)

driver.close()
    
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
df.to_csv('Rozetka_parcer_{cur_data}.csv')
```

Comment: Ага, принцип команды я понял, но тем не менее элемент не находит, не смотря на правки, а если в 
`t_name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__title').text`

заменю все на driver, то выводит опять же только один элемент

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, такое может быть если элемент с `goods-tile__title` не является вложенным элементом у элемента с `.goods-tile__picture.ng-star-inserted`. Этот момент я не проверял, нужно посмотреть

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII, ну да, у вас в `items` не родительские элементы выбираются. Обновлю ответ. Кст, не уверен, что поиск нужно включать класс `ng-star-inserted`, скорее всего, без него будет работать, возможно, он используется для фильтрации :)

Comment: Добрый день, у меня к вам небольшая просьба, если вас не затруднит и если у вас будет время, не могли бы вы обратить внимание на данную ошибку, не понимаю в чем проблема
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339523/message-invalid-type-null-expected-a-string-at-line-1-column-12